# Promtail force lowercase on log_level: "error" from (?P<log_error>(error|Error|ERROR))

Tags: regex, grafana-loki, promtail

I'm trying to create two labels(/values) to filter my logs on: `warning` and `error`. For graphing and logline panels.

I'm thinking `log_level: warning` or `log_level: error`. However, `log_error:`  and `log_warning:`  would also work. But with the code below, grafana/loki groups amd distinguishes my label values based on all the different variations.

```
- match:
    selector: '{job="varlogs"}'
    stages:
    - regex:
        expression: '.*(?P<log_error>(error|Error|ERROR)).*'
    - labels:
        log_error:

- match:
    selector: '{job="varlogs"}'
    stages:
    - regex:
        expression: '.*(?P<log_warning>(warn|Warn|WARN|warning|Warning|WARNING)).*'
    - labels:
        log_warning:
```

This works on the Loki side: `{host="$host", filename=~"$log_type"} |~"(?i)error"`. But I prefer them straight as labels before they come in.

Anybody got tips to force lowercase (on the promtail side)?

Comment: Does including the case-insensitive flag `(?i)` in the regex in the config not give you a (static) label you can reference in a query (e.g. `{log_level: "warning"}`)? Or are you trying to have a single 'match' rule with a dynamic `log_level` label that is normalized (lowercased & expanded abbreviations (e.g. "warn"))? From what I can tell, the reason there is a different label for each case variant is that the sample uses dynamic labels & capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question correctly, the reason the sample config produces labels with varying case is that it uses dynamic labels taken from a named group in the regex. Consequently, if a log line contained (e.g.) "Error", it would have a log_error label "Error" (rather than "error", which is desired). Instead of a dynamic label, you should be able to use a static label. Additionally, it should be possible to add the case-insensitive flag to the patterns so that the case variants don't need to be specified. Perhaps something like:

```
- match:
    selector: '{job="varlogs"}'
    stages:
    - regex:
        expression: '(?i).*\berror\b.*'
    - labels:
        log_level: error

- match:
    selector: '{job="varlogs"}'
    stages:
    - regex:
        expression: '(?i).*\bwarn(ing)\b.*'
    - labels:
        log_level: warning
```

This could then be queried with:

```
{host="$host", filename=~"$log_type", log_level="warning"}
```

Alternatively, instead of testing for a specific label value, the presence of the label itself can be tested for by matching it against a `.+` regex (this is suggested by the [Prometheus querying documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors), which is referenced by the Grafana Loki [log stream selector](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#log-stream-selector) documentation). With the config in the question, you'd use:

```
{host="$host", filename=~"$log_type", log_error=~".+"}
```

Caveat: untested. I'm not a Grafana Loki user, nor do I have access to a server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the specified answer. I'm suffering a bug https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/1502 .. So changing my loki setup to MinIO s3 like backend before I can continu and test your solution ;)